# Searching a key in a circular right shifted sorted array in log N time complexity

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given a circular right shifted sorted array with n elements. (Assume the number of shifts to be 'k', k is unknown here). It has been asked to search for a key in the array in **log n** time.

Example.

Given Circular Right Shifted Sorted Array : 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Search key 5.

Please note that the time complexity should be log n for the algorithm.

**My Approach :** Using binary search would give log n time complexity, however, we need a sorted array for that. But a shifted array loses its sorted order after the shift and sorting it again in log n time complexity is the part which I am not getting. **Please note that 'k' is unknown here.**

Can we even solve this in log n time complexity?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Use a binary search to find the discontinuity (to find **k** basically) and then a second binary search to find the key. In terms of *O* complexity, `2 log N` is the same as `log N`.

Comment: On every step divide circle in 3 equal parts, analyze 3 values and cut out some arc from the circle.

Comment: The linked duplicate is, in fact, a duplicate, and includes a clear answer.

Comment: Thank you guys, found the answer.